# Optional closures in swift 5

Tags: swift, swift5

I have been having trouble figuring out how to write an optional closure for swift 5. I have found a lot of explanations that are a few years old and none of them seem to work now.
I have tried:

```
func test(completion: (() -> Void)?){
    completion()
}
```

and other variations of that. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The completion in your test method is just fine. But when you call completion you need to do it this way: `completion?()`. What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: You can check this too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59332093/10124991

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming when you say "how to write an optional closure" you mean "how to *call* an optional closure", because you've written the closure parameter just fine, but you're just not calling it correctly.

To call an optional closure, you need to unwrap it first. Either:

```
completion?()
```

or:

```
if let unwrappedCompletion = completion {
    unwrappedCompletion()
}
```